# Recursive database queries using CodeIgniter (fixed)

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, recursion, hierarchical-data

ı need to get categories id from my table and my table is like this ;

```
categories
id| name                    |parent
1 | shoes                   |0
2 | women_shoes             |1
3 | man_shoes               |1
4 | sweets                  |0
5 | man_sweets              |4
6 | women_sweets            |4
7 | women_red_sweets        |6
8 | women_green_sweets      |6
9 | men_blue_sweets         |5
```

ı ı use Codeigniter 3 and ı need an array that has categories id
this is PHP code that is in the helper file;

```
function categories_list($id = 0, &$list = array()) { /// parent_id
    $ci = & get_instance();
    $cat = $ci->db->select("*")
                 ->from("categories")
                 ->where("parent",$id)
                 ->get()->result();
           
    foreach ($cat as $value) {
        array_push($list,$value->id);
        categories_list($list->id,$list);
    }
    return ($list);
}

$liste = categories_list(0);
print_r($liste);
```

This code just prints `array(1,4)`, but I need an array like this: `array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)`.

How can I create this correctly?

Fixed I should use & charecter for referance before $list=array(), it should be &$list=array()

Comment: Is `$$` in the function parameter wanted? Makes no sense there. Did you mean `&$`?

Comment: @halo why is `9` not in your expected results.

Comment: I fixed the problem, ı should use & charecter for referance before $list. it should be &$list=array()

Answer (score 0):

As you recurse with that call to `categorie_list()`, you are not actually feeding its returned array into the current level's array payload.  This can be done with `array_merge()` or with `array_push()` and the spread operator.  This will contain redundant ids because of the categories data.  You can call `array_unique()` if you want to remove duplicates.

The following snippet should be able to help you move forward so that you can refine your approach.

Code: (non-CodeIgniter [PHPize.online Demo](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/39ba393f38a84e7c734fbfb95f243e83/php/php81/041dcd6ac92942a46b9425f8ab44dd41/))

```
function categories_list($id = 0, $list = []) {
    $ci = &get_instance();
    foreach ($ci->db->get_where('categories', ['parent', $id])->result() as $row) {
        $list[] = $row->id;
        array_push($list, ...categories_list($row->id, $list));
    }
    return array_unique($list);
}

var_export(categories_list());
```